# How to set the number of rows and columns of GtkGrid?

Tags: gtk, gtk3, gnome

The gtk Devhelp recommends me to use GtkGrid instead of GtkTable. The function gtk_grid_new() is to create a new GtkGrid. There may be some rows and columns in a grid. However gtk_grid_new() can't set the number of rows and columns of GtkGrid. How to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Instead, when you add widgets to the grid with `gtk_grid_attach()` or similar functions, the number of rows and columns adapts to fit the rows and columns where you have placed the widgets.

Comment: If I place one widget in a grid, how many columns and rows will the grid have?

Comment: If you place it at row M and column N, the grid will contain M rows and N columns :-)

But note that, unless you explicitly set the `row-homogeneous` and/or `column-homogeneous` properties to true, the unfilled columns and rows can have 0 width and height.